# Trying to read a row of 2D vector that matches some of the values in it

Tags: c++, c++11

i need to search the vector State_actions if the values IsNow.get_pos(),IsNow.get_ang(),IsNow.get_spe(),ToBeDone.ste(),ToBeDone.acc(),ToBeDone.bra() exists in it, but they are not the only values in it, it also contains w0...w6. is there any way to search for those specific values

tried std::search and std::find

```
    .h

        class Sarsa:virtual public State,virtual public Action, public Agent {
            public:
                std::vector<float> ActionWeights(Action a);
                bool IsStateActionSeen(int st, int y);
                void AddStateAction(std::vector<float> statess);
        private:
                float reward;
                float w0,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6;

                std::vector<float> state_action_weights;
                std::vector<float> States_Actions;
                //sensor for lap
                tCarRaceInfo time;
        };

    .cpp


          Sarsa::Sarsa()        
            {
                State();
                Agent();
                Action();
                this->e = 0.0f;
                this->loadpolicy="Q.txt";
                this->savepolicy="";
                this->w0=0.2f;
                this->w1=0.2f;
                this->w2=0.2f;
                this->w3=0.2f;
                this->w4=0.2f;
                this->w5=0.2f;
                this->w6=0.2f;


                std::cout<<"Sarsa initialized \n";
}


 bool Sarsa::IsStateActionSeen(int st, int y)//x is state and y is action too many abriviations..
            {   
            //The position of state and action in their respected vectors
            State IsNow = all_states.at(st);
            Action ToBeDone = all_actions.at(y);
            std::cout<<"The State is: "<<IsNow.get_pos()<<" "<<IsNow.get_ang()<<" "<<IsNow.get_spe()<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"The Action is: "<<ToBeDone.ste()<<" "<<ToBeDone.acc()<<" "<<ToBeDone.bra()<<std::endl;
            //create a vector with values of both current state and action
            std::vector<float> State_action;
            std::vector<float> State_action_w;
            State_action={IsNow.get_pos(),IsNow.get_ang(),IsNow.get_spe(),ToBeDone.ste(),ToBeDone.acc(),ToBeDone.bra()};
            State_action_w={w0,IsNow.get_pos(),w1,IsNow.get_ang(),w2,IsNow.get_spe(),w3,ToBeDone.ste(),w4,ToBeDone.acc(),w5,ToBeDone.bra(),w6};
            //read the state actions from vector and check if they are seen, if not insert them.
                auto it = std::search(States_Actions.begin(), States_Actions.end(), State_action.begin(), State_action.end());
                    if (it != States_Actions.end())
                    {   

                        std::cout<<"Action found: "<<e<<"\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout<<"Action not fount.\n";
                        States_Actions.insert(States_Actions.end(),State_action_w.begin(),State_action_w.end());
                    }

        }
```

Comment: Code is incomplete. At least we need the `Sarsa` class definition to know what is local and what is class member. Also, where do `w0` .. `w6` come from?

Comment: fixed it, is it understandable now?

Comment: I still think you should consider rewording your question. It's a little hard to understand what it is about.

Comment: i need to search the vector State_actions if the values IsNow.get_pos(),IsNow.get_ang(),IsNow.get_spe(),ToBeDone.ste(),ToBeDone.acc(),ToBeDone.bra() exists in it, but that are not the only values in it, it also contains w0...w6. is there any way to search for those specific values